# Pipeline design

Tags: weblogic, osb

I have got the following question about the pipeline design..

Can you please help me understand what we should be doing inside the request pipeline and response pipeline?

Let's say.. I am designing a proxy service that calls 2 separate business services and sends the response to the caller..
The proxy service will have assign, service callout, routing and reply action.  I can do everything inside the request pipeline and I don't understand the purpose of the response pipeline.

Can anyone help me understand what we should be doing inside the response pipeline?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical scenario in an OSB pipeline would be to validate, transform and enrich the request in the Request Pipeline, Route to a business service (which appears after the pipeline pair), then validate, transform and enrich the response in the Response Pipeline.  In this case in your pipeline, after the Pipeline Pair node, you will have a Route node.

Often people will use a service callout instead of a Route node.  In that case, you may not have anything (like a Route node) appearing after your pipeline pair and you can do everything in the Request pipeline.

You should understand the difference between a Route node and a Service Callout.  Routing to a business service uses non blocking IO compared to a Service Callout which will block a thread, so using a Route is the much more scalable option.